# How to make this Javascript run in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I'm not sure why my code isn't working/ outputting correctly. I've hard coded and simplified things to get it to run in Qualtrics. It's looks long, but it's mostly just dealing with the variables.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function () {
    var response1 = "${q://QID4/SelectedAnswerRecode/1}"
    var response2 = "${q://QID4/SelectedAnswerRecode/2"
    var response3 = "${q://QID4/SelectedAnswerRecode/3}"
    var response4 = "${q://QID4/SelectedAnswerRecode/4}"
    var response5 = "${q://QID4/SelectedAnswerRecode/5}"
    var response6 = "${q://QID4/SelectedAnswerRecode/6}"
    var response7 = "${q://QID4/SelectedAnswerRecode/7}"
    var response8 = "${q://QID4/SelectedAnswerRecode/8}"
    var response9 = "${q://QID4/SelectedAnswerRecode/9}"
    var response10 = "${q://QID4/SelectedAnswerRecode/10}"

    R1 = parseInt(response1);
    R2 = parseInt(response2);
    R3 = parseInt(response3);
    R4 = parseInt(response4);
    R5 = parseInt(response5);
    R6 = parseInt(response6);
    R7 = parseInt(response7);
    R8 = parseInt(response8);
    R9 = parseInt(response9);
    R10 = parseInt(response10);
    block_1 = [R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8, R9, R10]

    var switchpoint1 = R1 - R2;
    var switchpoint2 = R2 - R3;
    var switchpoint3 = R3 - R4;
    var switchpoint4 = R4 - R5;
    var switchpoint5 = R5 - R6;
    var switchpoint6 = R6 - R7;
    var switchpoint7 = R7 - R8;
    var switchpoint8 = R8 - R9;
    var switchpoint9 = R9 - R10;
    var all_switchpoints = [switchpoint1, switchpoint2, switchpoint3,
        switchpoint4, switchpoint5, switchpoint6, switchpoint7,
        switchpoint8, switchpoint9];

    var lambda_mat;
    lambda_mat = [.7, .9, 1.1, 1.3, 1.5, 1.7, 1.9, 2.1, 2.3];

    var find_1_lambda;
    find_1_lambda = all_switchpoints * lambda_mat;

    var filtered_switchpoint;
    filtered_switchpoint = all_switchpoints.filter(0);

    var l_block_1
    if (filtered_switchpoint.length > 1) {
        l_block_1 = 0;
    }
    else {
        l_block_1 = filtered_switchpoint;
    }
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("Lambda_Block_1", l_block_1)
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("b1_responses", block_1)
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("the_switchpoints",
        all_switchpoints)
});
```

Does this look right? Thanks in advance!

Comment: On a quick glance, it looks like R1 - R10 are never defined as variables. this could be part of your problem.

Comment: Add var in front of block_1 too. In addition, you are missing a semi-colon after var l_block_1.  Also, you are trying to save arrays as embedded variables.  You have to convert them to strings first.